# R: add column to dataframe, named based on formula

Tags: r, dataframe, rename, col

More 'feels like it should be' simple stuff which seems to be eluding me today. Thanks in advance for assistance.

Within a loop, that's within a function, I'm trying to add a column, and name it based on a formula.

I can bind a column & its name is taken from the bound object: `data<-cbind(data,bothdata)`

I can bind a column & manually name the bound object: `data<-cbind(data,newname=bothdata)`

I can bind a column which is the product of an equation & manually name the bound object: `data<-cbind(data,newname2=bothdata-1)`

Or another way: `data <- transform(data, newColumn = bothdata-1)`

What I can't do is have the name be the product of a formula. My actual formula-derived example name is `paste("E_wgt",rev(which(rev(Esteps) == q))-1,"%")` & equation for column: `baddata - q`.

A simpler one: `data<-cbind(data,paste("magic",100,"beans")=bothdata-1)`. This fails because `cbind` isn't expecting the `=` even though it's fine in previous examples. Same fail for `transform`.

My first thought was `assign` but while I've used this successfully for creating forumla-named objects, I can't see how to get it to work for formula-named *columns*.

If I use an intermediary step to put the naming formula in an object container then use that, e.g.:

```
name <- paste("magic",100,"beans")
data<-cbind(data,name=bothdata-1)
```

the column name is "name" not "magic100beans". If I `assign` the equation result to an formula-named object:

```
assign(paste("magic",100,"beans"),bothdata-1)
```

Then try to cbind that via `get`:

```
data<-cbind(data,get(paste("magic",100,"beans")))
```

The column is called "get(paste("magic",100,"beans"))". Boo! Any thoughts anyone? It occurs to me that I can do `cbind` then separately `colnames(data)[ncol(data)] <- paste("magic",100,"beans"))` which I guess I'll settle for for now, but would still be interested to find if there was a direct way.

Thanks.

Comment: It may help you to know that `data$col1` is the same than `data[,"col1"]` which is the same than `data[,x]` if `x` is `"col1"`. This is how I usually access/set columns programmatically.

Comment: Another way to it is just to set the names afterwards with `setNames` or `\`names<-\``.

Comment: thanks antoine. I'm still not aware how one would set the names if using [,x] rather than $x...

Comment: I posted an answer to show you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chances are that `cbind` is overkill for your use case.  In almost every instance, you can simply mutate the underlying data frame using `data$newname2 <- data$bothdata - 1`.

In the case where the name of the column is dynamic, you can just refer to it using the `[[` operator -- `data[["newcol"]] <- data$newname + 1`.  See `?'['` and `?'[.data.frame'` for other tips and usages.

EDIT: Incorporated @Marek's suggestion for `[["newcol"]]` instead of `[, "newcol"]`

Comment: that's the ticket, thanks user. I'd forgotten that assigning data to a non-existent [,column] in a df puts it in a new column with that name. Cheers! :)

Comment: `data[["newcol"]] <- data$newname + 1` is cleaner way to create new column

Answer (score 2):

It may help you to know that `data$col1` is the same than `data[,"col1"]` which is the same than `data[,x]` if `x` is "col1". This is how I usually access/set columns programmatically.

So this should work:

```
name <- paste("magic",100,"beans")
data[,name] <- obsdata-1
```

Note that you don't have to use the temporary variable `name`. This is equivalent to:

```
data$magic100beans <- obsdata-1
```

Itself equivalent, for a data.frame, to:

```
data<-cbind(data, magic100beans=bothdata-1)
```

Just so you know, you could also set the names afterwards:

```
old_names <- names(data)
name <- paste("magic",100,"beans")

data <- cbind(data, bothdata-1)

data <- setNames(data, c(old_names, name))
# or
names(data) <- c(old_names, name)
```

Comment: thanks Antoine. I was using colnames to set afterwards  but [,newname] is what I needed. Cheers!